# Is query result null?

Tags: php, mysql

This is for a data import script, I want to check if the Category Name with a Parent ID already exists; if it does then it does not need to be added to the database. My check however is not stopping duplicate entries.

```
$i = 1;
$check = FALSE;
echo'<br>';
do{
   //Turn import order into Colewood order. 
   $tieroffset = $i - 1;

   $tier = $csvdata[$r][$fields["Tier" . $i]];

   $query = ("SELECT name FROM base_categories WHERE name = '".$tier."' AND id = '".$tieroffset."'");
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $result_array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

   if (empty($result_array)) {

       if($tier != null){ 
       $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO base_categories (parent_id,name) 
                        VALUES ('" . $tieroffset . "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($csvdata[$r][$fields["Tier" . $i]]) . "')";
       }

        mysql_query($queryInsert);

        print_r($queryInsert);
   }                

   $i++;
}while ($i <= 6 || $check != FALSE);
echo'    >>>END PRODUCT<br>';
```

Comment: depreciation of mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mysql_num_rows function to check the number of rows returned by the query.

```
if (empty($result_array)) {
```

to

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 ) {
```

Comment: Tried this and I am still getting duplicate results; am I right to have used $result = mysql_query($query); to get my query results? This really does not make sense to me!

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` returns *`FALSE`* if there are no more rows and always use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or PDO to avoid *SQL Injection*.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result)
 {
  if(($result_array = mysql_fetch_array($result)) //while
   {
    //code
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First a small return question:

If your {parent_id, name} combination cannot contain duplicates why are they not a unique constraint???

If you add that you are sure never to get a duplicate key in those two columns. If they are they only colums you could also make them the primary key together.

Next if you have done that you could suffice with just one query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO base_categories (parent_id, name) VALUES('" . 
         $tieroffset . "', '" . 
         mysql_real_escape_string($csvdata[$r][$fields["Tier" . $i]]) . "') 
         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = name;
```

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updates your old record when an UNIQUE constraint OR PRIMARY KEY constraint fails. This way you only have to run one query in stead of two.